# How can I change an user input char eg. "abcDEF" and return an output "222333"

Tags: c++

How can I change an user input char eg. "abcDEF"
and return an output "222333" without using atoi or stringstream

using the traditional SMS idea where 
2 is equal to abc
3 is equal to def
4 is equal to ghi
etc.

Comment: it's kind of a small educational problem i would give to juniors studying programming for the first year :) what's your question - to write code for you? i see no question otherwise...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lookup key map then transform your string. A sample with C++11 lambda and C++03:

```
static std::map<char, char> keyMap;

struct GetKey
{
  char operator()(char c)
  {
      return keyMap[c];
  } 
};

void InitKeyMap(std::map<char, char>& keys)
{
  keys['a'] = '2';
  keys['b'] = '2';
  keys['c'] = '2';
  keys['D'] = '3';
  keys['E'] = '3';
  keys['F'] = '3';
}

int main ()
{ 
  InitKeyMap(keyMap);
  std::string s1 = "abcDEF";

  // C++11 with lambda
  std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s1.begin(),
  [](const char c)->char{  return keyMap[c];});

  // C++03 
  std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s1.begin(), GetKey());

  cout << s1 << std::endl;

  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hold a table that maps each letter to a number, for instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string convert(const std::string& map, const std::string& input)
{
    std::string output(input.size(), '0');

    for (int i=0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        output[i] = map[input[i]];
    }
    return output;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string charMap(128, '0');
    // init table
    charMap['a']='2';
    charMap['A']='2';
    charMap['b']='2';
    // init all values ...

    std::string input("aAb");
    std::string result(convert(mapping, input));
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

My initial intention of this answer was to give the op the basic idea of using a LUT and to supply him with a straight-forward (technically correct) solution to his problem. I did not expect all the harsh comments. I changed the solution to be a bit more C++ and less C. There are obviously more ways and other mechanisms in C++ to solve this question.

Comment: Showing a beginner to use `malloc`, `memset` and `free` like this in a C++ program isn't such a good idea. Better use `std::string` and `std::map`.

Comment: Agreed - giving a C answer to a C++ question = automatic down-vote.

Comment: I was under the impression that C++ is a multi paradigm language, C included. This a valid solution to his question. You can choose not to upvote, but you dont have to downvote. I gave him the IDEA of how to solve the problem, with a sample! You don't have to feed the person with a spoon.

Comment: I get the idea of using Array where i could hold every single alphabet.

Comment: It is a valid but *bad* solution that would not pass any code review.

Comment: I don't see any reason for massively downvoting this answer, since it's technically correct. You stubborn C++ guys, I'd be curious what you would do if someone didn't put the cushioned chair of the STL under your lazy bottoms.

Comment: Changed to C++. @juanchopanza, I was under the impression that the op is a beginner, this isn't going to any code review! Wouldn't you prefer giving him a solution he can read line by line and understand, rather than giving him a 1-liner lamba expression that he has no idea what is going on there ? Definitely not the way to teach a beginner.

Comment: Well, in my experience one reason behind then tons of bad, buggy C++ I have to deal with every day is that newcomers learn how to do things with C idioms and never learn to use idiomatic C++. A one-liner with a lamda expression is probably one step too far (and only available in C++11), but `std::string` and `std::map` are very easy to use and intuitive (and do not require any explicit memory management).

Comment: H2CO3: We would write it :) I didn't know that programming should be an act of self-mortification. I thought it was about writing robust, maintainable code.

Comment: @juanchopanza using `std::map` for a constant LUT is overkill and wasteful

Comment: @Itsik really? and your mapping[256] isn't saving anything but worse.

Comment: @billz How is it worse? `O(1)` vs. `O(logn)`. 128 bytes vs. red-black tree. Please explain (and obviously for this answer the table is small, but I'm talking about the general idea)

Comment: @Itsik trade speed with memory doesn't always mean a win, lookup 26 characters, speed will NEVER an issue.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Well, you certainly would, it's just that the attitude doesn't show that.

Comment: @billz You write that it is WORSE like there is some sort of major issue with using the static array, when there is practically no difference in the 26 char case. The real problem I have with all the above commenters is that you are so single and closed-minded with your "ideal idiomatic c++" code is that you are missing the main point that you have a real beginner in front of you and that he will  probably benefit most from the simplest and easiest solution to understand.

Comment: @billz In addition, the table is more like 60+ chars (uppercase, lowercase, some symbols maybe), which means that each lookup is really 5 operations and not 1. If you are in a system that is constantly converting strings, I'm pretty sure speed WILL be an issue and by changing the map to an array you will feel the difference

Comment: memset, malloc and free are hadly ever the "easiest solution to understand". Also, when someone asks for a solution in some language, I expect the solution to use the best practices of that language. Otherwise he could conclude that using malloc/free is cmmon practice and good style in C++.

Comment: It is straight forward and nothing is happening behind the scenes. Imo it's best to learn the basics bottom up. After you understand the concepts you can progress to better robust c++ code

Comment: @juanchopanza: you nailed it right here when you said: *"Well, in my experience one reason behind then tons of bad, buggy C++ I have to deal with every day is that newcomers learn how to do things with C idioms and never learn to use idiomatic C++."*. A pity I can only up-vote this once, as it sums up the whole problem of bad C++ programming, i.e. using C++ as if it were "C with objects".

Comment: @Itsik: even though you've mixed in some token C++ in your code above it's still a horrible mix of C and C++ - e.g. why use both `char *` and `std::string` ?

Comment: @PaulR: Why does having `char*` disqualify it from being proper C++ code? Every mechanism in the language has a purpose and in this case I thought a static array was proper. What is so horrible about having a char array for LUT instead of `std::map`? Please convince me, I'm not against criticism or learning

Comment: @Itsik: my objection was mainly the mixing of two different string types in one function. If you feel that a std::map is overkill you could still use a std::string for your LUT.

Comment: @PaulR: The intention of the `char*` is array of chars and not a string. Theoretically they are the same but the intention is different. I agree that std::string can be used instead. In any case, I think calling the code horrible because of that is a bit exaggerated

Comment: OK - question is closed now, but if you want more input then I suggest posting your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com and invite further comment.

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the the question or an answer. Please do that and if needed, continue the discussion in the chat!